# Kotlin class inheritance throws error for 'gradle build' when used with Spring Data & @Entity

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data

I have a simple entity called `Character` and looking like this:

```kotlin
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"character\"")
class Character(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    position: Position,
) : GameEntity(position) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Character

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id.hashCode()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Character(id='$id', name='$name', position=$position)"
    }

}
```

It derives from `GameEntity` that is simply this:

```kotlin
open class GameEntity(
    val position: Position
)
```

When I run `gradle clean build` the following Exception is thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No noarg super constructor for CLASS CLASS name:Character modality:OPEN visibility:public superTypes:[com.barbarus.state.entity.GameEntity]:
CONSTRUCTOR IR_EXTERNAL_DECLARATION_STUB visibility:public <> (position:com.barbarus.state.entity.Position) returnType:com.barbarus.state.entity.GameEntity [primary]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg.NoArgIrTransformer.getOrGenerateNoArgConstructor(NoArgIrGenerationExtension.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg.NoArgIrTransformer.visitClass(NoArgIrGenerationExtension.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg.NoArgIrTransformer.visitClass(NoArgIrGenerationExtension.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg.NoArgIrTransformer.visitClass(NoArgIrGenerationExtension.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:55
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to add a no-arg constructor to your `GameEntity` class as follows:

```kotlin
open class GameEntity(val position: String) {
    constructor(): this("")
}
```

The same might be true regarding `Character`, because JPA requires a no-arg constructor to be available in the JPA entities:

> An entity class must follow these requirements.
>
> - The class must be annotated with the javax.persistence.Entity    annotation.
> - The class must have a public or protected, no-argument    constructor. The class may have other constructors.
> - (...)

You can read more at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm.